# Visual Studio, C++, new Header and Source file I create no longer able to #include other project files correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Ok a cat on keyboard may be involved.

Now whenever I add a new source or header file to my project and try and include other header files from that project several things happen. Other header files no longer show up in the auto complete list, and once the names are entered I get a red line under the include that states "cannot open source file xxx"

This only applies to newly created files, the old files can still include other files form the project. Also a yellow bar appears on both the right scroll bar and left of the screen (between the text and the line numbers), also on the right scroll bar, red dots show up to indicate errors, including the failed includes.

Biggest issue is I lose all auto complete references to my other code. I assume some settings have been adjusted through the keyboard but I can not for the life of me figure out what the changes are, and it has effectively tanked my project.

Comment: I guess the include directories in the project settings have been messed up. Or the solution configuration was switched to another one where the correct settings haven't been applied.

Comment: A general tip: Version control (also for project files) helps for avoiding these kind of problems.